# How can I transfer files between storage drives?

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, boot, file-transfer

Sorry if this is a very basic question, I am just hopeless at computers!

So in my case, I have an old 1TB HDD that I plan to supplement with a new 250GB SSD as a boot drive.

My old HDD has Win 7, but I have a copy of Win 10 that I want to do a fresh install for on my new SSD. How would I go about with this? I believe I have all the appropriate cables, SATA power and data.

Would it then be possible to boot up from my SSD, delete the OS from my HDD while preserving my data files on it?

Thanks!

Comment: It seems like you've got a few steps to do, something like this would do the job:
- Install OS onto SSD
- Copy important files/data to a temporary storage location (on the SSD, another HDD or a large USB flash drive)
- Format HDD so it can be used as a storage drive

I do not believe there is a way to quickly/easily 'remove a windows installation barring user data' from the HDD (which would leave it in a sort of storage disk setup).

Comment: You say you want to add a supplementary drive, so why copy anything? I wouldn't delete anything from the HDD until you have everything working as you want in W10, but retain a dual-boot system, so that you can switch to W7 any time you need to.

Answer (score 1):

I would do this the following way:

- Connect only the SSD to the computer (make sure the old hard drive is disconnected for the moment just to be sure nothing goes wrong during partition selection in the setup)
- Once you finished installing Windows 10 and any additional drivers (if needed), turn off the computer
- Connect the old hard drive to the computer using another SATA port (you should have one SSD and one hard drive connected to the mainboard)
- Turn on the computer and wait for the HDD's driver installation (a restart may be required)
- After the machine reboots (if it needed), you're ready to go !

Now you will have the files available anytime (you don't need to copy them, you can leave the computer like this.

Note: Make sure to select the SSD as the boot drive in the BIOS after the third step.